# VS2010 Crystal-Reports: "Invalid Keycode"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

On a legacy product I successfully migrated to VS2010 about a month ago: When I open it today and try to launch the Crystal Reports editor I get an error "Invalid Keycode" and a blank editor screen.

VS2010
Windows 7, 64b

Most advice is pointing me towards "Reinstall VS2010" - but I've also found a few forum posts indicating a keycode fix or registry edit.  I've tried a few of these, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got to uninstall "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 - Beta x" and install the release version which can be downloaded from: http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0.exe.

The beta expired on 12/31/2010

Comment: More info on the release version here: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/22083

Comment: It was a pretty unpleasant surprise to see when I came back from my holiday.

Comment: I have install this also but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports is no longer included with VS2010.  I suspect that might have something to do with it.  Here's [a blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140726125931/http://scn.sap.com/people/blair.wheadon/blog/2009/12/10/crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2010) from the company that owns it now that tells you why you should be happy about that.  I don't understand much of it, but then again I also don't understand why companies like SAP are still in business.

Comment: I forgot about Crystal being an additional install of their beta release for VS2010.  Followed your blog post to the production release announcement here: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/22083 , and am installing now.

Answer (score 1):

Acording with SENC4ME said, You can try to change the date of your system, change it to Nov/01/2010. I had the same problem y when I changed the date the problem was fixed.

Comment: Changing date is good to see if the problem is actually about the beta version, which in my case was! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have suffered from this issue for the last 2 days.
I think this issue occurred before installing Visual studio 2008. I originally installed Visual studio 2010 and Crystal report V13.
Make a back up copy of registry files of business objects by right clicking on the business object, then select export and then execute the registry file to your target machine.
If your OS installed into different directory then you have to make change the path and the common directory.

See screen shot for more help:
[image: screen short of the registry back up of crystal report key code issue for 10.5]

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling / repairing Visual Studio is the only thing that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Crystal Reports 13.0.18 works for me, but I have to do it after any session in VS2010 where I touch the reports. Next time I try it I get the Invalid Keycode msgbox. This is mildly irritating to say the least.